# Convert a class object to a DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have a simple class:

```
public class Employee
{
     public string firstName { get; set; }
     public string lastName { get; set; }
}


Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.firstName = "joe";
emp.lastName = "smith";
```

What I'm looking for is a way to easily map these values to a web control, for example a `DataGrid`.

```
datagrid1.DataSource = emp;
```

If I try straight out I get an error:

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource,
>   IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Any suggestions regarding the best way to achieve this appreciated.

Comment: You can bind `List<Employee>`

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error clearly saying the `DataSource` expects an `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource` but you are sending a one instance of the `Employee`. You can use a [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) with only one item like this:

```
datagrid1.DataSource = new List<Employee> {emp};
```